# Gravity Forms Woocommerce Product Page Ajax on Multistep Form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

Here is an example of it not working: `http://wafpro.com/product/waf-pro-dedicate-website-coverage/` the form is at the end of the page. Please note that once you add your information and press "next" the whole page refreshes and you have to scroll back down to continue with the form.

Please reference: `http://wafpro.com/` the vulnerability scan form and how it works in ajax and keeps the user on that section upon clicking "next". This is how the product page should work.

My forms are already rendered through gravity forms and are designed with multistep and conditional logic elements. I have a plugin that integrates Gravity Forms with WooCommerce: `www.woothemes.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/`
With this plugin on product page ajax works with modifying the sub total and total cost but does not work with multistep forms.

Here is a copy of the woocommerce-gravityforms-product-addons/gravityforms-product-addons-ajax.php

```
<?php class woocommerce_gravityforms_product_form {
private $current_page;
private $next_page;
private $form_id = 0;
private $product_id = 0;
public function __construct($form_id, $product_id) {
    $this->form_id = $form_id;
    $this->product_id = $product_id;
    add_filter('gform_form_tag', array(&$this, 'on_form_tag'), 10, 2);
    add_filter('gform_submit_button', array(&$this, 'on_submit_button'), 10, 2);
}

function get_form($options) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $product = null;
    if (function_exists('get_product')) {
        $product = get_product($this->product_id);
    } else {
        $product = new WC_Product($this->product_id);
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'display_title' => true,
        'display_description' => true,
        'display_inactive' => false,
        'field_values' => false,
        'ajax' => false,
        'tabindex' => 1,
        'label_subtotal' => __('Subtotal', 'wc_gf_addons'),
        'label_options' => __('Options', 'wc_gf_addons'),
        'label_total' => __('Total', 'wc_gf_addons'),
        'disable_label_subtotal' => 'no',
        'disable_label_options' => 'no',
        'disable_label_total' => 'no',
        'disable_calculations' => 'no'
            ), $options));

    //Get the form meta so we can make sure the form exists.
    $form_meta = RGFormsModel::get_form_meta($this->form_id);
    if (!empty($form_meta)) {

        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $_POST['gform_submit'] = isset($_POST['gform_old_submit']) ? $_POST['gform_old_submit'] : '';
            $_POST['gform_old_submit'] = $_POST['gform_submit'];
        }

        $form = RGForms::get_form($this->form_id, $display_title, $display_description, $display_inactive, $field_values, $ajax, $tabindex);

        unset($_POST['gform_submit']);
        $form = str_replace('</form>', '', $form);

        $form = str_replace('gform_submit', 'gform_old_submit', $form);

        $this->current_page = GFFormDisplay::get_current_page($this->form_id);
        $this->next_page = $this->current_page + 1;
        $this->previous_page = $this->current_page - 1;
        $this->next_page = $this->next_page > $this->get_max_page_number($form_meta) ? 0 : $this->next_page;

        if ($product->product_type == 'variable' || $product->product_type == 'variable-subscription') {
            echo '<div class="gform_variation_wrapper gform_wrapper single_variation_wrap">';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="gform_variation_wrapper gform_wrapper">';
        }

        if ($product->is_type('variable')) :
            //echo '<input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="variation" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="' . $this->product_id . '" />';
        elseif ($product->has_child()) :
            //echo '<input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="group" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="' . $this->product_id . '" />';
        else :
            //echo '<input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="' . $this->product_id . '" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="' . $this->product_id . '" />';
        endif;

        if (wc_is_21x()) {
            wp_nonce_field('add_to_cart');
        } else {
            $woocommerce->nonce_field('add_to_cart');
        }

        echo '<a id="_form_' . $this->form_id . '" href="#_form_' . $this->form_id . '" class="gform_anchor"></a>';
        echo $form;

        echo '<input type="hidden" name="gform_form_id" id="gform_form_id" value="' . $this->form_id . '" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" id="woocommerce_get_action" value="" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" id="woocommerce_product_base_price" value="' . $product->get_price() . '" />';

        $description_class = rgar($form_meta, "descriptionPlacement") == "above" ? "description_above" : "description_below";
        ?>

        <?php
        $this->on_print_scripts();

        if ($disable_calculations == 'no') :
            ?>

            <div class="product_totals">
                <ul id="gform_totals_<?php echo $this->form_id; ?>" class="gform_fields <?php echo $form_meta['labelPlacement'] . ' ' . $description_class; ?>">
                    <li class="gfield" <?php
                    if ($disable_label_subtotal == 'yes')
                        echo 'style="display:none;"';
                    ?> >
                        <label class="gfield_label"><?php echo $label_subtotal; ?></label>
                        <div class="ginput_container">
                            <span class="formattedBasePrice ginput_total"></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="gfield" <?php
                    if ($disable_label_options == 'yes')
                        echo 'style="display:none;"';
                    ?> >
                        <label class="gfield_label"><?php echo $label_options; ?></label>
                        <div class="ginput_container">
                            <span class="formattedVariationTotal ginput_total"></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="gfield" <?php
                    if ($disable_label_total == 'yes')
                        echo 'style="display:none;"';
                    ?> >
                        <label class="gfield_label"><?php echo $label_total; ?></label>
                        <div class="ginput_container">
                            <span class="formattedTotalPrice ginput_total"></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <style>
                .single_variation .price {
                    display:none !important;
                }
            </style>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <style>
            .hidden-total {
                display:none !important;
            }
        </style>



        <?php
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

// filter out the Gravity Form form tag so all we have are the fields
function on_form_tag($form_tag, $form) {
    if ($form['id'] != $this->form_id) {
        return $form_tag;
    }

    return '';
}

// filter the Gravity Forms button type
function on_submit_button($button, $form) {
    if ($form['id'] != $this->form_id) {
        return $button;
    }

    return '';
}

function on_print_scripts() {


    $garvityforms_params = array(
        'form_id' => $this->form_id,
        'next_page' => $this->next_page,
        'previous_page' => $this->previous_page,
    );

    wp_localize_script('wc-gravityforms-product-addons', 'gravityforms_params', $garvityforms_params);
    ?>
    <script>
        gravityforms_params = <?php echo json_encode($garvityforms_params); ?>;

        gform.addFilter('gform_product_total', function(total, formId) {
            return update_dynamic_price(total);
        });

    </script>
    <?php
}

private function get_max_page_number($form) {
    $page_number = 0;
    foreach ($form["fields"] as $field) {
        if ($field["type"] == "page") {
            $page_number++;
        }
    }
    return $page_number == 0 ? 0 : $page_number + 1;
}
```

}?>

I modified the settings

```
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'display_title' => true,
    'display_description' => true,
    'display_inactive' => false,
    'field_values' => false,
    'ajax' => false,
    'tabindex' => 1,
    'label_subtotal' => __('Subtotal', 'wc_gf_addons'),
    'label_options' => __('Options', 'wc_gf_addons'),
    'label_total' => __('Total', 'wc_gf_addons'),
    'disable_label_subtotal' => 'no',
    'disable_label_options' => 'no',
    'disable_label_total' => 'no',
    'disable_calculations' => 'no'
        ), $options));
```

so `'ajax' => false,` was `'ajax' => true,` and upon clicking "next" the form on /waf-pro-dedicate-website-coverage/ changes to /#_form_1 and renders a blank page.

What needs to be modified for ajax to work on multistep forms on product pages without page having refreshing and user losing position on the page?

Comment: were you able to solve it? I am too after this.